# Add HTML/Web front end to existing Java framework

Tags: java, html, maven

I'd like to know the best and easiest method to implement a HTML website so that i can pass data to an existing java application (on the back end) where it can process the data/results to return it back to front end.

I've came across solutions like CRUD, Spring, Sprint Boot. But i want the simplest means to exploit data being passed to and from a website and my already existing java(maven) application. What would be the best route to explore?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, the question as it currently stands is an opinion-based question and such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: You can use Spring MVC, for example. Here is a step by step tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial with the source code on GitHub.

Comment: As noted this question is off-topic here. See the sister site Software Recommendations Stack Exchange. Tip: see several Answers there discussing [Vaadin](https://www.Vaadin.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another Stack Exchange site: Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.